# Orientdb maximum number of classes

Tags: schema, orientdb, orientdb2.2

The orientdb documentation doesn't say anything about limitations regarding the number of classes. In practise it seems a large number of classes is limiting functionality.

I have a database with the Buildingsmart IFC classes as it's schema. This means I have a lot of classes. Every time a connection to the db is made, the server sends the complete list of classes (clusters). As a result, opening my database is taking too much time.

Is there a way to tell orientdb not to sent the list? I already know the internal db class structure, so I don't really have need for the list.

Comment: Hi @Maarten Veerman, which version of orientdb you use?

Comment: @Idacrema 2.2.35, mainly because the "official PHP driver" doesn't work with the 3.x versions yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum number of classes supported by OrientDB is a function of number of clusters in the database. Refer [the clustering section](https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/gettingstarted/Tutorial-Clusters.md).

> Starting from v2.2, OrientDB automatically may create multiple
> clusters per each Class to
> improve the performance of parallelism. The number of clusters created
> per class is equal to the number of CPU cores available on the server.
> You can also have more clusters per class. The limit on the number of
> clusters in a database is 32,767 (or, 2<sup>15</sup> - 1)

For CPU of 4 core, therefore, assuming each class has default number of clusters, the total class count in the database would be ~8100.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've stopped using orientdb a year ago. It just was not up to the job, in terms of PHP connectivity, slow database opening with large number of classes, and very slow queries in cases where nodes have a lot of edges (although this could arguably be my db design flaw). All in all it was just to limited. I now use Mariadb, which always me to set better indexes, and with CTE's in able to perform super fast hierarchical queries. I'll except the answer, since it answer the question in the title. The issue with the slow database opening is still open though.